# Twitter Connector Tweet issue in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have started playing with Azure Logic and I'm using the Twitter Connector.

What I have done is I'm searching for tweets with a specific #Tag and then try to tweet the found item in the next step.

It works all fine when I put this in the Tweet step:

```
@first(body('twitterconnector')).TweetText
```

Now what I need is to add a fix string to this tweet and whatever i try it gives me this error:

Save logic app failed

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"The template validation failed: 'The template action 'twitterconnector0' at line '1' and column '1709' is not valid: \"Unable to parse template language expression 'first(body('twitterconnector')).TweetText Via': expected token 'EndOfData' and actual 'Identifier'.\".'."}}
```

I have tried:

```
@first(body('twitterconnector')).TweetText @Via
```

and

```
@first(body('twitterconnector')).TweetText + "Via"
```

and

```
@first(body('twitterconnector')).TweetText + Via
```

and

```
@first(body('twitterconnector')).TweetText Via
```

And none of these seem to work and all fail with the above error.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@concat` function to concat two strings like this:

```
@concat(first(body('twitterconnector')).TweetText, "test string")
```

Take a look at this "Logic App Workflow Definition Language" for your reference and should be easy enough to do string manipulations like this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn948512.aspx